# pass extra value manually using chagePage

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

how to `pass a hash value manually to a next page` in jquery mobile and receive it in a `pagecreate / pageshow`

i tried following when a button gets clicked on page1

```
   $.mobile.changePage('#page2?val=1', { 
                transition: 'slideup'       
            }

           );
```

**HTML Page Code**

```
<html>
<head><title>jQuery Mobile Test</title></head>
<body>
    <div id="page1" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Page 1</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            Place content here
            // i tried this too but didnt receive at the pagecreate of pge 1
            <a href="#page2?val=1" data-role="button">Send Value</a>            

        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>Footer</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="page2" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Page 2</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            Place content here
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>Footer</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If `#page2` is part of the same DOM, what about just setting a local variable and retrieve it that way?

Comment: If a page gets refresh then i will lost the value , page1 and page2 are in one html file only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it looks like jqm does not support this:

> jQuery Mobile does not support query parameter passing to
>   internal/embedded pages.

However, their documentation offers to plugins that may help you:

> There are two plugins that you can add to your project if query
>   parameters are needed between pages. There is a lightweight page
>   [params plugin](https://github.com/jblas/jquery-mobile-plugins/tree/master/page-params) and a more fully featured [jQuery Mobile router plugin](https://github.com/azicchetti/jquerymobile-router)
>   for use with backbone.js or spine.js.

Found in the section called "Passing parameters between pages" here: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

Comment: thanks, I almost wired up some jsfiddle to parse the params, then I found that documentation.

Comment: @Hunt, no problem.  Does that answer your question?